# update value by key of json array inside nested json java

Tags: java, json, object, lombok, rest-assured

I am able to update the value of jsonObject by using key name , here the method which I am using

```
private static JSONObject setValue(JSONObject json, String key, String newValue) throws JSONException {
        Iterator<?> keys = json.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String k = (String) keys.next();
            if (key.equals(k)) {
                json.put(key, newValue);
            }
            Object value = json.opt(k);
            if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                setValue((JSONObject) value, key, newValue);
            }

        }
        return json;
    }
```

But this is not working in case of JSONArray object , I tried surfing , tried some method but not able to get desire output , an sample request payload:

```
{
    "sactions": [
        {
            "fund": "REAL",
            "amount": {
                "value": 130.24,
                "curr": "RMB"
            },
            "type": "TD",
            "desc": "TD",
            "code": "PROMO",
            "id": "deaedd69e3-6707-4b27-940a-39c3b64abdc7"
        }
    ]
}
```

Looking an recursive method to update value for any given key.

This is what I tried , but did not work

```
public static JSONObject setProperty(JSONObject js1, String keys, String valueNew) throws JSONException {
    String[] keyMain = keys.split("\\.");
    for (String keym : keyMain) {
        Iterator<?> iterator = js1.keys();
        String key = null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            key = (String) iterator.next();
            if ((js1.optJSONArray(key) == null) && (js1.optJSONObject(key) == null)) {
                if ((key.equals(keym))) {
                    js1.put(key, valueNew);
                    return js1;
                }
            }
            if (js1.optJSONObject(key) != null) {
                if ((key.equals(keym))) {
                    js1 = js1.getJSONObject(key);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (js1.optJSONArray(key) != null) {
                JSONArray jArray = js1.getJSONArray(key);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    js1 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return js1;
}
```

This is how I am using the method (Ceating request body using lombok and jakson)

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String.valueOf(setValue(new JSONObject(mapper.writeValueAsString(transferFund())),
                    field, " "))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [JsonPath jayway](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to save your time.

For example:

```
String jsonInput = "{\n" +
                "    \"sactions\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"fund\": \"REAL\",\n" +
                "            \"amount\": {\n" +
                "                \"value\": 130.24,\n" +
                "                \"curr\": \"RMB\"\n" +
                "            },\n" +
                "            \"type\": \"TD\",\n" +
                "            \"desc\": \"TD\",\n" +
                "            \"code\": \"PROMO\",\n" +
                "            \"id\": \"deaedd69e3-6707-4b27-940a-39c3b64abdc7\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}";

String newJson = JsonPath.parse(jsonInput).set("$..id", "test").jsonString();
System.out.println(newJson);
```

Comment: Agreed , but needed to work on Objects Mapper as this what they need.